# Given a set $U=\{1,2,3,...n\}$. How to partition elements in $U$ into sets $A$ and $B$ such that the sum of the elements in $A$ and $B$ is in minimum.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I came across a particular problem wherein I think the answer would necessitate me to partition $U=\{1,2,3,...n\}$ into subsets $A$ and $B$ such that the **sum** of the elements in $A,B$ is at minimum.

To show that it is in minimum, the following should hold:

Let:

$sumA$ be the sum of the elements in $A$

$sumB$ be the sum of the elements in $B$

Then $sumA,sumB$ is at $minimum$ when $|sumA-sumB|$ is at $minimum$.

**Possible Cases:**

We are actually looking for all subsets of $U$. The number of subsets of $U$ is $2^n$.

Example: Let $U$={1,2,}. Then the number of subsets are $2^2=4$:

$\{1,2\}$,$\{1\}$,$\{2\}$,$\{\}$

We will drop  $\{1,2\}$,$\{\}$ since they irrelevant to our task. So there should be $2^n-2$ possible subsets to be paired, in this case $\{1\}$,$\{2\}$.

Let $p$ be the possible subsets, then:
$$p=2^n-2$$

The number of ways to arrange these subsets into $2$ sets is $p\cdot\ (p-1)=2^n-2 \cdot\ (2^n-3)$.

**Problem:** My problem is to figure out what will be the exact combination of subsets $A,B$ such that $sumA$ and $sumB$ is at the minimum. Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Ah, a _partition_ is more restrictive then just a collection of subsets.  In order for $A,B$ to be a partition of $U$, you must have that $U=A\cup B$ and that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.  ie, $A$ and $B$ must be disjoint and their union must be all of $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split them into consecutive groups of $4$ starting with the largest ( so the first block is $\{n-3,n-2,n-1,n\}$ ) and in each group $\{a,a+1,a+2,a+3\}$ split them so  $a$ and $a+3$ are in $A$ and $a+1$ and $a+2$ are in $B$.

If the number of elements is a multiple of $4$ we are done.

If the remainder is $1$ put $1$ in $A$.

If the remainder is $2$ put $1$ in $A$ and $2$ in $B$.

If the remainder is $3$ put $1$ and $2$ in $A$ and $3$ in $B$.

It is not hard to see this is optimal.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ contains *an odd number of odd numbers*, therefore it is impossible for sum$A$ and sum$B$ to have the same parity (proves optimality in the second case).

Comment: That's right! There is a time to live, and a time to sleep.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer but could you cite an example on your method described above? Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using your notation we immediately see that sumA + sumB = sumU.  Ideally, we want sumA = sumB because then both are minimum.  There are numerous ways of doing this, so here is one way.  Set R = n mod 4.  If n is divisible by 4 then R is zero.  Otherwise, R is either 1, 2, or 3.  Now consider the set {R+1, R+2, R+3, … n-1, n}.  We can pair these up by matching the first and last and placing alternate pairs in set A and set B.  This will give identical sums in both sets of (n+R)(n+R+1)/4 for each set.  This leaves us with the first R elements which also need to be allocated.  There are four cases to consider:

R = 0 - nothing left to allocate

R = 1 - place the remaining "1" in either set and the difference is just 1

R = 2 - place the remaining "1" in one set and the "2" in the other set and the difference is still only 1.

R = 3 - place "1" and "2" in one set and "3" in the other set and both sums are the same.